# C pass on to argument on which array to work on

Tags: c, arrays, function, parameters, arguments

I apologize if this is a repeated question, but I can't seem to find the keywords to search for the question that I'm about to ask.

Basically, I have defined myself a struct.

```
#define max_terms 101

typedef struct{
    int row, col, value;
} term;
```

Now I have three different terms namely, a[max_terms], b[max_terms] and c[max_terms]
I would like to input into the following function's parameter, so that I can choose to work on which of the three defined arrays

```
void input(/*parameter here*/){
    a[0].row = 0; // want to be able to choose the array to work on instead of just a
}
```

Thank you for reading!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach would be to pass a pointer to the first element of the array to the function.

```
void input(term *a)
{
    a[0].row = 0;
}
```

/* ... */

```
term b[max_terms];
input(b);
```

---

As [giorashc](https://stackoverflow.com/users/986169/giorashc) notes in the comments, if the arrays don't all use the same size you'll want to pass the actual size as an additional parameter.

Comment: Passing the size also might be a good way of not overflowing the given array

Answer (score 1):

You have two common options:

```
void input(term *t, size_t size)
```

and:

```
void input(term t[], size_t size)
```

Both mean the same. Passing an argument works the same for both. When you have:

```
term t[SIZE];
```

Then either of those will work:

```
input(&t[0], SIZE);
```

or:

```
input(t, SIZE);
```

Obviously, the second is more convenient. It means the same as the first one; it's just a shorter way to write it. C allows that because passing the address of the first element of an array is a very common operation.